# how to make build and how make build folder structure same as reactjs in next js version 14?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

[This image is the build structure of reactjs I want to build something like this in nextjs v14]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3alIO.png

I have written this code in NextJS v14

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    output: 'export',
};
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
```

**app/abbreviations/[abbrDetail]/page.js**

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}detail? 
       name=test&tbl=abbreviation`);
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            return data.map((post) => ({
            slug: post.abbre,
        }))
        } else {
            return { data: null };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return { data: null };
    }
}


async function getAbbreviationDetail(name) {
    const response = fetch(`${API_URL}detail?name=${name}&tbl=abbreviation`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                return {
                    data
                };
            } else {
                return { data: [] };
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return { data: [] };
        });
    return response
}
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't work and this error show

[TypeError: result is not iterable]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I68XR.png